# Dijkstra's algorithm - comparisons in priority queue

Tags: c++, algorithm, set, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

I've copied dijkstra's algorithm in C++ [from this page](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#C.2B.2B) and modified it to suit my graph representation classes. Basically, I replaced only `std::pair` as template parameter to `std::set` by my own structure `edge`:

```
struct edge
{
    int vertex;
    unsigned long weight;

    edge(int v = 0, unsigned long wt = 0) : vertex(v), weight(wt) { }

    bool operator<(const edge& e2) const
    {
        //return weight < e2.weight;
        return weight < e2.weight || ((e2.weight >= weight) && vertex < e2.vertex);
    }
};
```

However, I had to implement operator< similarly to the one found in std::pair. When I use commented return statement, the outputs are wrong. But the longer statement returns `true` if `e2.weight >= weight` (so `e2.weight` might actually **be bigger** than `weight`) as long as `vertex < e2.vertex`. But vertex numbers do not appear in the definition of the Dijkstra's algorithm.

So how come the program is working properly with only the second return statement?

Comment: what does `int vertex` represent?

Comment: The same thing what `second` in `std::pair` in the linked page.

Comment: in the page you linked, the second element is a `vertex_t`. It uses an `int` so it has a unique identifier - the magnitude of the int has no significance (so using it in a comparison makes no sense)

Comment: `vertex_t` in that page is the currently processed neighbour of a vertex popped off the `std::set` at the beginning of `while` loop. Its value is significant because it simply denotes a vertex to which the `weight_t` refers to. But I agree that it makes no sense in a comparison - however, like I said, the first return statement in my `operator<` casues my program to fail on the biggest input test on some online judge (gives wrong answer). This test contains over 5k vertices and more than 100k edges, so it's hard for me to examine its behavior during the run-time.

Comment: Might it have to do with the fact that `set` is automatically ordered according to some `operator<()` on its elements, so that in this case, where a `set` is used, the magnitude of `vertex` might carry useful information regarding its ordering in relation to other elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rephrasing the correct return statement:

```
return (this->weight < e2.weight) || ((this->weight <= e2.weight) && this->vertex < e2.vertex);
```

equivalent to:

```
return (this->weight < e2.weight) || ((this->weight == e2.weight) && this->vertex < e2.vertex);
```

(<= breaks down into == because of the shortcircuiting from the first condition)

so I want my weight to be lesser.... or if equal, the vertex to be lesser.

**edit** (misunderstood the original why does it fail phrasing):
A standard set requires a strict ordering....

As you insert graph edges, the weights of these edges can be the same - and therefore, weights alone aren't a unique identifier for your edges, so it is not about a logical ordering mechanism as per Djikstra's - it is a way of holding all your edges without overwriting one another in the set.

For a more obvious failure case, try doing this with both definitions of op<:

```
//int verticeIdx[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3} 
int constWeight = 3;
edge myEdge(0, constWeight), myNewEdge(1, constWeight);
std::set<edge> edges;
edges.insert(myEdge);
edges.insert(myNewEdge);
std::cout << edges.size();
```

Comment: Yeah, I've just noticed that we can break down `<=` into `==`... Thanks to considering `vertex` in `operator<`, those elements are  sorted both on weight and vertex number (in that order) - like you said. But the definition of the Dijkstra's algorithm reads that we have just to take off the element from the container with the lowest weight - **it says nothing about considering vertex numbers as well in case of duplicated weights**. That's why I don't know why my first return statement makes the algorithm incorrect.

Comment: @Quentin, if the operator<() seems a bit too logically inconsistent for you, you could do this:
........
struct EdgeSetLesser { bool operator() (const edge& lhs, const edge& rhs) {  /*first weight then vertex*/ }   }
.............
std::set<edge, **EdgeSetLesser** > myEdges;
.............
This allows you to use a separate comparator based on weights for Djikstra, and arrange/organize based on different criteria.

Comment: Awww, I totally forgot about the fact that "weights alone aren't a unique identifier for your edges". It's all clear now, thanks!